# Java equivalent for Spark code on Pregel API

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, graph, apache-spark-sql, spark-graphx

I am writing pregel on a graph of format `Graph<Row,Row>` which is having vertex computation argument in scala as

```
(_,a,b) => a+b
```

I am trying to convert it into Java function which is having Signature as

```
Function3<Object, VD, A, VD> arg4
```

I understand that VD will be of Row type, A is aggregate message but what will be the return type in Java as should it be of mutable nature due to reccuring computation at particular vertex?

```
new Function3<Row, Double, Row, Row>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Row call(Row arg0, Double arg1, Row arg2) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right so using [Function3](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function3.html), according to this signature - `(_,a,b) => a+b`, you must ignore the first argument and add the last two, but your signature `public Row call(Row arg0, Double arg1, Row arg2)` is wrong, `arg2` must have `Double` type, change to:

```
new Function3<Row, Double, Double, Row>()
```

Here you ignore first parameter Row, and add second and third and wrap it to return type Row.

Comment: what should be the return type as the recurrent addition of each node will occur and return type should be mutable according to my understanding?